# Jquery Datatabase Json error

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc

I am calling a method which returns a entity with quite a field child entity.I don't need the child entity but because they are in relationship therefore i can't get rip of it.

I am getting the response correctly when i check the json data.But when i set a breakpoint at datatable.

```
 mRender: function (data, type, row) {
```

the row is looping through json data CHAR BY CHAR

`

```
    $('#serviceTB').DataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        destroy: true,
        searching: true,
        "info": true,
        "pageLength": 10,
        "lengthMenu": [[10, 20, 50, -1], [10, 20, 50, "All"]],
        "sDom": "<'top'f>rt<'fluid-row'<'col-md-5 col-sm-12'i><'col-md-7 col-sm-12'p>><'fluid-row'<'col-md-12 col-sm-12'<'pull-right'l>>>",
        "columns": [
          { "data": "article_number", "orderable": true, "searchable": true },
                { "data": "serial_number", "orderable": true, "searchable": true },
           { "data": "description", "orderable": false, "searchable": false },
            { "data": "Purchase_date", "orderable": true, "searchable": false },
            { "data": "rental_agreement", "orderable": false, "searchable": true },
            { "data": "service_agreement", "orderable": false, "searchable": true },
              { "data": "Warranty", "orderable": true, "searchable": true },
             /* EDIT */ {
                 mRender: function (data, type, row) {
                     debugger



                 }
             },
        ], "ajax": {
            "url": "@Url.Action("GetMachineOwnerByType", "WMFMachine")",

            "type": "GET"
        }
    });
}`
```

Below is my json result which contains all the fields required by the jquery

```
public JsonResult GetMachineOwnerByType(int draw, int start, int length, string searchstring = "", string orderstring = "", int ordercol = 0)  
    {

        string search = Request.QueryString["search[value]"];
        string order = Request.QueryString["order[0][dir]"];
        int sortColumn = int.Parse(Request.QueryString["order[0][column]"]);
        searchstring = search;
        orderstring = order;
        ordercol = sortColumn;
        var result = service.GetListWMFMachineByType(draw, start, length, searchstring, orderstring, ordercol, "M");//mylogic to get the Model 

        return new JsonResult { Data = result, MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
    }
```

`
**Model CLass**

```
  public class JsonTableModel
{

    public int draw { get; set; }
    public int recordsTotal { get; set; }
    public int recordsFiltered { get; set; }
    public object data { get; set; }

}
```

**logic**

```
 dt.data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(mymodel, Formatting.None,
        new JsonSerializerSettings()
        {
            ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore,
            PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.None

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

OK solved. i turn off the

```
 db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
```

i don't know is it the correct way. but it solved the problem . i have been digging on this probleming since 6 hours ago.

after turning this off. i just throw in the original entity and did not do any serialize to the object.